# Wordpress: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()

Tags: php, wordpress

I got an error when I run Wordpress:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home3/adjaya/public_html/wp-content/themes/jobboard/plugin/includes/stats.php on line 24 and defined in /home3/adjaya/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1152

stats.php on line 24:

```
return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query));
```

wp-db.php on line 1152:

```
public function prepare( $query, $args ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says that you are missing a second parameter, and looking at `public function prepare( $query, $args ) {` tells you that you need to add a `$args` parameter to the call.

Edit: take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error; Google will show you the causes and fixes for this error caused by incorrect usage of `$wpdb` that is vulnerable to SQL injection. There are also many answers already on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Missing+argument+2+for+wpdb+prepare

See the WordPress post on how to correct the error: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/

See if there is an update for your jobboard theme: http://themeforest.net/item/jobboard-responsive-job-resume-market-wordpress-theme/9321086

Basically, you need the correct number of arguments for `$wpdb`

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = %d AND name = %s", $id, $name );
```